# Why is crashed in NSRangeException?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml

I parse xml string with XMLDictionary from https://github.com/nicklockwood/XMLDictionary .
I have this code:

```
NSURL *URL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[self.rssFeed objectAtIndex:i]];
                        NSString *xmlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:URL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];

                        NSDictionary *xmlDoc = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithXMLString:xmlString];
                        NSMutableArray *aux = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[[xmlDoc valueForKey:@"channel"]valueForKey:@"item"]];
```

and crashed at this line:

```
NSString *xmlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:URL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
```

with this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 5 beyond bounds for empty array'
```

Have someone any ideas? Curious: App not crashed every time when i running this code. 
This part of method is  performSelectorInBackground. I think  is a value is changing

Comment: Study the error message, try to figure out what it means as it applies to the line the app crashed on. If necessary ask for help about what part you do not understand. Add a breakpoint at that line and examine the variable values. Add log statements if necessary. You really need to be able to understand Objective-C error messages and debug problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I reckon it's crashing on the line before:

```
NSURL *URL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[self.rssFeed objectAtIndex:i]];
```

Put a breakpoint on this line, and see how many items are in your `self.rssFeed` array...

*(Spoiler alert: your array is actually empty.)*

Good luck.

Comment: 12 items. I checked :)

Comment: Damn !!  Okay, then I split the objectAtIndex call into its own line of code - create an NSString containing the appropriate value in your array, then (in the next line of code) create an NSURL out of it.   Xcode still reckons you have an 'empty array' for some reason.  Perhaps that 5'th value is blank/nil or something...?

Comment: ...And another test:  In the NSURL line of code, get rid of the [self.rssFeed objectAtIndex...] section, and see what happens if you just hardcode a URL string in it instead.   Does the error go away?

Comment: (lldb) po [arrayFeed objectAtIndex:i]
http://rss.lemonde.fr/c/205/f/3050/index.rss

(lldb) po [arrayFeed objectAtIndex:i+1]
http://www.lequipe.fr/rss/actu_rss.xml

Comment: arrayFeed is new array. I create a new array and initializing it to make sure is not a problem with array.

Comment: i already try with a static string. And crashed again. Very strange.

Comment: Could you try with a completely different URL  (eg https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=jack+johnson)

Comment: Same. The problem is only method is performed in background.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81007/discussion-between-mike-gledhill-and-gaby-fitcal).